# How to show password by using setTransformationMethod(null), yet retain the eye icon

Tags: android

Currently, I design my password input text field as following

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/trading_activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/trading_activity_horizontal_margin"

    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TradingWizardTextInputLayout"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    android:id="@+id/password_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/wizard_password"
        android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"

        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

It looks as following

[image]

However, at initial stage, I would like to have my password input text field's input, to be visible.

This means, when the password input text field first appear, it should look like this

[image]

I had tried

```
passwordEditText.setTransformationMethod(null)
```

The password is visible. However, it will also make the eye icon disappear!

[image]

How can I show password by using `setTransformationMethod(null)`, yet retain the eye icon?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't change anything. There's still a diagonal cross sign across eye icon, and password is still not visible.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
```

you could set a "drawableRight" and a touchListener to get the same effect.
The code will be something like this

**XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/password_text_input"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:hintEnabled="false"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_18"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_18">
                    <EditText
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:paddingTop="0dp"
                        android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_hide_password"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**TouchListener**

```
public class ShowHidePassword implements View.OnTouchListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
        EditText editView = (EditText) v;
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (event.getRawX() >= (editView.getRight() - editView.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                editView.requestFocus();
                if(editView.getTransformationMethod() instanceof PasswordTransformationMethod){
                    editView.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                    editView.setSelection(editView.getText().length());
                    editView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_hide_password, 0);
                }else{
                    editView.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                    editView.setSelection(editView.getText().length());
                    editView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_view_password, 0);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and set the listener in your activity

```
passwordEditText.setOnTouchListener(new ShowHidePassword());
```

hope this helps.